# set atribute QtRadioButton using name of the QtRadioButton from the string

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to set atribute QtRadioButton using name of the QtRadioButton from the string. But I'm not doing well. I also tried locals(). But it can only assign a value to a variable.

This works:

```
typ = "E"
locals()["self.pocetParciel"+typ] = 0
print(locals()["self.pocetParciel"+typ])
```

This doesn't work:
`locals()["self.radioButton"+typ].setEnabled(True)`

Prints an error: KeyError: 'self.radioButtonE'

I also tried exec() but it didn't help.
I thank you in advance for your help.

globals(), locals(), exec()

Comment: Don't use globals, locals, exec or eval unless you **really** know what you're doing.